# Discogs api oauth: authenticate/identity

Tags: oauth, identity

I'm trying to build a .net program that helps me organizing my vinyls. For that I use the discogs API. I'm having problems with the oauth procedure. The first 4 steps were succesful; I received an access_token and access_token_secret (using the request_token, request_token_secret and verifier). Only the last step is giving me problems: the identity check to see if I (the user) am succesfully authorized. According to the [discogs APi documentation](http://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:authentication,header:authentication-oauth-flow)  it should be enought to send the access_token and access_token_secret to /oauth/identity but I keep getting a '502 bad gateway' response.

This is the request I send:

```
Public Function makeTestRequest()
    Dim requestResult As String = ""
    Dim user_agent As String = "ll// .01 DiscogsTestApp"
    Dim oauth_consumer_key As String = "AAA"
    Dim oauth_token As String = "BBB"
    oauth_signature_method = "PLAINTEXT"
    Dim oauth_signature As String = "CCC&" & "DDD"
    oauth_timestamp = setTimeStamp()
    oauth_nonce = setNounce()

    'Set authorization header
    Dim headerFormat As String = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=""{0}"",oauth_nonce=""{1}"",oauth_token""{2}"",oauth_signature""{3}"",oauth_signature_method""{4}"",oauth_timestamp""{5}"""
    'Dim authHeader As String = String.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version))

    'set the request
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse
    Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    Dim requestUrl3 As String = "http://api.discogs.com/oauth/identity"
    request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl3)
    request.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = 0
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.UserAgent = "user_agent"
    request.Timeout = -1
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)

    Try
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        streamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encode)
        requestResult = streamReader.ReadLine
        request.Abort()
        streamReader.Close()
        streamReader = Nothing
        response.Close()
        response = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    Return requestResult

End Function
```

As you see I send more than just access_token and secret (according to [this](https://holtstrom.com/michael/blog/post/518/Discogs-OAuth-Authorization-Headers.html) example)

So this keeps giving me a '502 bad gateway' response... Does anyone have an idea what is causing this? Perhaps any ideas that I can try?

Just for info: the post request for requesting access_token works fine, here is the code:

```
 Public Function makeFinalRequest()
    Dim requestResult As String = ""
    oauth_nonce = setNounce()
    oauth_timestamp = setTimeStamp()
    Dim oauth_signature As String = Form1.txtconsumer_secret.Text & Form1.txtoauth_token_secret.Text
    oauth_consumer_key = Form1.txtconsumer_key.Text
    oauth_signature_method = "PLAINTEXT"
    Dim oauth_token As String = Form1.txtoauth_token.Text          
    Dim oauth_verifier As String = Form1.txtverifier.Text        
    Dim user_agent As String = "ll// .01 DiscogsTestApp"
    oauth_token_secret = Form1.txtoauth_token_secret.Text
    Dim oauth_version As String = "1.0"

    'Set authorization header
    Dim headerFormat As String = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=""{0}"", oauth_nonce=""{1}"",oauth_token=""{2}"",oauth_signature=""{3}"",oauth_signature_method=""{4}"",oauth_timestamp=""{5}"",oauth_verifier=""{6}"",oauth_version=""{7}"""
    Dim authHeader As String = String.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_verifier), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version))

    'set the request
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse

    Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    Dim requestUrl2 As String = "https://api.discogs.com/oauth/access_token"
    request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl2)
    request.UserAgent = user_agent
    request.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    request.Method = "POST"
    'request.ContentLength =
    request.Timeout = -1
    request.ContentLength = 0
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)

    Try
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        streamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encode)
        requestResult = streamReader.ReadLine
        request.Abort()
        streamReader.Close()
        streamReader = Nothing
        response.Close()
        response = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    Return requestResult

End Function
```

Please let me know if I need to post more details...
Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the TLS version of the endpoint, e.g. `https://..`?